# Mysql rows to columns query

Tags: mysql, function

I am hoping this is a relatively simple question to answer.  I have a list of transactions in a database table and I want to extract into columns an enum value (y/n) to each motorcycle manufacturer that exists in that table.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT
accCode,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'HON') purchasedHonda,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'YAM') purchasedYamaha,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'KAW') purchasedKawsaki,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'SUZ') purchasedSuzuki,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'DUC') purchasedDucati,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'KTM') purchasedKTM,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'SYM') purchasedSym,
rnFuncBool(accCode,'VIC') purchasedVictory
FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold WHERE accCode<>'' GROUP BY accCode
```

and the function rnFuncBool is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `phcontacts`$$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `rnFuncBool`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `rnFuncBool`(
fnAccCode VARCHAR(6),
fnAccMan VARCHAR(3)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(1) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold WHERE accCode=fnAccCode COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AND vehichleManufacturer=fnAccMan COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci )>0 THEN
    RETURN 'y';
ELSE
    RETURN 'n';
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Whilst this seems a really logical solution for a quick return the main table contains over 48,000 rows and so the execution time is in the minutes.

I did try working with a join on a temporary table but that only returned one manufacturer when grouped by the customer account code.

Of course I could try group_concat but that is not what I really want to achieve.

If anybody has any thoughts on how I can achieve this that would be brilliant.

As always many thanks in advance.

Cheers
Graham

Comment: This is a FAQ, search for "mysql pivot" and you'll find lots of questions and answers.

Comment: sample data plus a sample desired output can gretly increase your chances of getting an answer. I'm personally not going to decipher your queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go for boolean 1/0 instead of y/n then you can greatly simplify things for yourself and do a cross-tab problem query which'll be way more efficient...

```
SELECT
accCode,
SUM(CASE WHEN accCode ='HON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) purchasedHonda,
SUM(CASE WHEN accCode='YAM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  purchasedYamaha,
...
SUM(CASE WHEN accCode='VIC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  purchasedVictory
FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold WHERE accCode<>'' 
GROUP BY accCode
```

That being said, your code and what I've shown an abridged amendment to is grouping by accCode, which is what you've said you want, but I'm not sure how much value there is for you unless you're looking to construct a lookup table or something similar in which case you could simply get a list of distinct accCode and do the rest by hand or in excel just as quickly as writing sql to do it.

Comment: Using a boolean 1/0 isn't really the key to the improvement; the key is the  elimination of the unnecessary recursive SQL using an aggregate on an expression.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get "looping" like this in a design, there is frequently a much more efficient design.

It's hard to figure out why you would need a udf, and why that queries the same table, and why that query needs to be performed 8 times for every row in the table (or, more precisely every row where accCode<>''). If 48,000 rows match the criteria in that outer query, that's going to be 384,000 calls to the function, which is going to be a total 384,001 queries executed against the database.

I just can't fathom why you would need to do that, to get the specified resultset.

It would be much more efficient to get the information in just one pass through the table, with a query something like this:

```
SELECT accCode
     , MAX(IF(vehichleManufacturer='HON','y','n')) AS purchasedHonda
     , MAX(IF(vehichleManufacturer='YAM','y','n')) AS purchasedYamaha
     , MAX(IF(vehichleManufacturer='KAW','y','n')) AS purchasedKawasaki
     , ...
  FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold
 WHERE accCode<>''
 GROUP
    BY accCode
```

Your function includes a specification that the comparison should be done case insensitive collation.  If you need to specify that, it can be done in the SQL

```
  , MAX(IF(vehichleManufacturer='HON' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,'y','n'))
```

That query is likely to benefit from a covering index on `accCode` and `vehichleManufacturer`.

(That's an odd spelling in that `vehichleManufacturer` column name.)

---

The MySQL-specific `IF()` function could be replaced with an equivalent ANSI `CASE` expression, e.g.:

```
  , MAX(CASE WHEN vehichleManufacturer='HON' THEN 'y' ELSE 'n' END)
```

Comment: Nice! After tripups with enums and max I think I've blocked using aggregations on anything text-based, which is a shame because this is a neat way of doing it.  :-) Although I do prefer CASE because it is more portable than IF

Comment: Good points. In this case, the MAX function is being applied to only two literal values, so there isn't anything to trip over, in this case. If you need SQL to be portable, then yes, an ANSI `CASE` expression is going to be preferred over the MySQL-specific `IF()` function.

Comment: Hi Spencer and Steph, many thanks for your help on this.  I did realise that I was going about this the completely wrong way and of course whilst I got the results I wanted my way, I know it was wrong.  My problem was that I had hit a mental brick wall and just couldn't figure out a way round it.  @StephLocke provided me with a good starting point which I implemented yesterday and your explanation Spencer has given me a much better insight into how things work, so many thanks to you both.  My updated answer is below, as for the spelling, yeah I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT accCode,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'HON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedHonda,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'YAM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedYamaha,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'KAW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedKawsaki,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'SUZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedSuzuki,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'DUC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedDucati,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'KTM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedKTM,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'SYM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedSym,
       case sum(CASE accCode WHEN 'VIC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            when 0 then 'n' else 'y' 
       end purchasedVictory
FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold WHERE accCode<>'' GROUP BY accCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Steph for your help on this. To explain the data is being exported to a CSV file for external use and so the system it is being imported into needs a flat file only.

I have modified your query slightly and hey presto it works:

```
SELECT accCode,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='HON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedHonda,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='KAW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedKawasaki,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='SUZ' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedSuzuki,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='DUC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedDucati,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='KTM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedKTM,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer` ='SYM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n')) purchasedSym,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer`='YAM' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n'))  purchasedYamaha,
(IF (SUM(CASE WHEN `vehichleManufacturer`='VIC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0,'y','n'))  purchasedVictory
FROM _emarsys_vehiclessold WHERE accCode<>'' 
GROUP BY accCode
```

Many thanks 
Graham

Comment: You could use a `MAX` function, and return 'y' and 'n' directly, in place of the `IF` and `SUM`.  (There's no need to calculate a SUM, you can return a 'y' if there is at least one row that satisfies the condition, and otherwise return an 'n'.)